# How to replicate Facebook's compose status screen for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, core-text

[image: Compose status message UIView in Facebook for iOS]

I'm trying to build a compose status screen for my app and I'm looking at Facebook for iOS for inspiration. Above is their compose status screen.

I understand that the top is simply the navigation bar, the bottom can be a simple view with buttons in it (I will actually just have the camera and location icons). However, I can't quite figure out what UI components make up the full-screen `UITextView` in the middle. I'm trying to replicate it, except without the profile pic on the upper left.

When you type a status message, it looks like an ordinary `UITextView`. However, when you tag a location, the `-- at (name of location)` is appended to the `UITextView` and moves with the end of your status as you type along. Now, I don't think that's a `UITextView` feature. Also, the location text is not editable. Even more so, `-- at` is not clickable, yet the location itself, in blue (in this case, Starbucks Coffee), is.

As for the photo attachment, I can imagine that it is simply a `UIImageView` added via `addSubview` to the parent view which contains it and whatever makes up the status and location altogether. My question is, exactly what makes them up?

What I've tried: Well I haven't really coded anything, but I've been looking around and checking out Core Text for a possible implementation. However, it doesn't feel like the right tool to use because the status message needs to be editable. As I understand, Core Text is useful only for rendering something like the location tag, but not editing text like the status message itself.

Answer (score 1):

For advanced text view, take a look at `UITextInput` protocol, it's pretty powerful and could give you what you need.